# How useful are reviews in magento?

Tags: review

I am about to launch an eshop and I am thinking to disable reviews. How useful do you think are product reviews?

Comment: Chrys, sorry to close but this question in its current form is so broad that it can only receive opinion-based answers. Perhaps you can provide a bit more content in your question regarding the nature of your business (e.g. products, market, etc.) which will allow for some evidence-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

The features of review

1) When you put as enable so user will write their reviews regarding this products. so any other user can see this review based on that you can increase your product cell.

2)you can marketing your products.

3) Based on this review you can analyse your products rating.

4) you can also got opinion form customers based on that you provides him discount on that products.

5) you can identify if your product review's are more then this product is very demanding in market. so you can increase price or give discount on this products.

there are so many more reason

review is more important for any site. If you are customer then you first prefer to read reviews and based on that you buy that products.